# Confusion about const declaration inside object

Tags: javascript, object

I came across this piece of code [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/multi-line-chart), and I noticed that `const data` is declared inside the brackets. I thought you had to use the `key: value` format inside the brackets when creating an object. How does this work?

```
data = {
  const data = await d3.tsv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/8033015/raw/01e8225d4a65aca6c759fe4b8c77179f446c5815/unemployment.tsv", (d, i, columns) => {
    return {
      name: d.name.replace(/, ([\w-]+).*/, " $1"),
      values: columns.slice(1).map(k => +d[k])
    };
  });
  return {
    y: "% Unemployment",
    series: data,
    dates: data.columns.slice(1).map(d3.utcParse("%Y-%m"))
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not valid javascript. The reason it works is that Observable has its own syntax. It's deliberately designed to be similar to javascript, but it isn't actually javascript. You can read more about this here:

https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript

Comment: Thank you! Was quite confused there for a bit. Will accept this answer shortly. :)

Answer (score 2):

The code above is not a valid javascript code.

observableHQ is using its own parser to achieve that https://github.com/observablehq/parser the code is translated to the following:

```javascript
const chart = (arguments) => {
  // code...
}
```